# Spring Batch and Entity Graph

Tags: spring-batch, jpa-2.1

I'm using the JpaPagingItemReader for my Reader and I would like to use a specific Entity Graph. Does anybody know, how to use JPA Entity Graph (JPA 2.1) with JpaPagingItemReader (Spring Batch 3.0.6)?

Comment: Have you found a solution since ? I'm also digging into this right now ...